# 2FA on RPi and trusted computers

Tags: ssh, remote

From what I've [read](http://msorin.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/enable-two-factor-authentication-for-the-ssh-on-your-raspberry-pi/), it is possible to set up 2-factor authentication on the RPi , but this is a rather tedious thing to install if access from random computers is infrequent (i.e. I mainly access the RPi from my own personal machines, but occasionally from other computers where I have no idea what's running).

My question: Is it possible to set it up, so that I can add my netbook as a "trusted" computer?
In case it matters, I'm running the latest version of Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

it's not like you log in to your raspberry from random computers in inet cafes and libraries?

then, from my point of view, you should generate RSA keypair on your computer:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

copy the public part to your raspi

```
ssh-copy-id USER@raspberry
```

disable password authentication by

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    PermitRootLogin no
    PasswordAuthentication no
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

and forget about this authentification issue because I've never heard about anyone had their computer hacked over SSH with only RSA keypair auth enabled.

Comment: Using 2-factor authentication would allow me to log into my pi from libraries, etc... without the risk of someone abusing my password (hence the question). RSA keypairs is a good suggestion, but doesn't protect a login from places like libraries. The RSA method also would not allow login from any machine that doesn't have a key (my work machines are shared, so I wouldn't want to store my private key there). So, while this is a good suggestion, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: you probably should not use public computers to log anywhere you care about security. keeping private key on the netbook and using only netbook to access your server sounds quite reasonable to me.

Comment: I don't usually log in from anywhere that I don't trust/public/random computers, but I thought I'd add an extra layer of security in case I needed to log in from my local library. Was just a thought.

Comment: @Brill - if your work machine is shared, any solution that enables password-less login from that computer would allow password-less login, regardless of if it's RSA key-based or not. Might I ask what kind of protection you are looking for vs a login from a library?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
There are 2 options (I went for option 2):
1. Run 2 SSH daemons, each configured to listen on a different port and then by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config appropriately, you can configure which authentication methods you can use.
2. Update Raspbian Wheezy SSH server with that of Jessie (which supports the "localport" attribute), by adding it to the apt-repository (don't forget to do `apt-get update` before trying to install the new SSH server!!!). Then edit your sshd_config file by including the match directive:

```
Match localport XX
                   RSAAuthentication yes
                   PasswordAuthentication no

Match localport YY
                   RSAAuthentication no
                   AuthenticationMethod keyboard-interactive:pam
                   PasswordAuthentication no
```

Just make sure that the sshd is listening on both ports XX and YY.